# Texturing: Texture not covering complete face

Tags: texturing

Can somebody please help me again? I am trying to put a texture on an apple model. I cut the apple in 2 halves and want to add a texture in the cut face.

Unfortunately the applied texture does not cover the whole face. Near the corner of the face the Textur does get stretched in a weird way.

I created the UV map with "Project from View". I saw this behaviour already in a different Project from me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem could arise from the fact that the face you are trying to uvmap is an ngon, a polygon with greater than 4 sides. Try pressing CTRL+F and select triangulate faces and then project again. Also make sure that your apple has no non-uniform scale.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. This has cured the situation on the boundries of the textures. Now I have some distortions in the middle. I try to improve them after work. :-)